# Execute fixture on skipped tests

Tags: typescript, playwright

I'm trying to export skipped tests into report. For that some code has to be executed for every such test, as in any other reporter fixture.

Unfortunately,

```js
test.skip('foo', () => { ... })
```

doesn't get exported, because no fixtures run on skipped tests, and the only extension point I've found to do that is a fixture.

There is a way to circumvent it with

```js
test('foo', () => {
  test.skip();
  ...
})
```

but it's highly error-prone. Developers tend to use `test.skip` on top level, and no linter rule is possible, because Playwright has `const test2 = test1.extend(...)` syntax.

Is there a way to run fixtures on skipped tests? Are there other options to run some code for each skipped test?

Comment: Hello, or i dont understand you correctly, or something else. Test fixture returns testInfo object with relevant info. If there is test.skip() the testInfo.status will be 'skipped.
Also its present in all of reports like a property skipped="1"
can you clarify what is the end goal ?